# OpenSSL ECB non 64 bits multiple plain text

Tags: c, security, openssl, des, ecb

I'm having problems when I try to cipher and decipher a non 64 bits multiple plain text using OpenSSL ECB problem.

I have two .c files, one to cipher, another one to decipher.

This is the first one.

```
// FILE ENCRYPTION
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void merror(char *msg) {
  perror(msg);
  exit(0);
}

char *Encriptar(char *Key, char *Msg, int size) {
  static char*    Res;
  int       n=0;
  DES_cblock      Key2;
  DES_key_schedule schedule;
  Res = ( char * ) malloc( size );

  memcpy( Key2, Key,8);
  DES_set_odd_parity( &Key2 );
  DES_set_key_checked( &Key2, &schedule );
  DES_ecb_encrypt((unsigned char *)Msg, (unsigned char *)Res, &schedule,DES_ENCRYPT);
  return (Res);
}

#define LINELEN 8

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n, fdp, fdc;
  char key[]="password";
  unsigned char buf[LINELEN];

  if (argc < 3) {fprintf(stderr,"USO %s <fileP> <fileC>\n",argv[0]);exit(0);}
  if ((fdp = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
     merror ("Open FDP");
   if ((fdc = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 00744)) == -1)
      merror ("Open FDC");
   while ((n = read(fdp, buf, LINELEN)) > 0) 
   write (fdc, Encriptar(key, buf, n), n);

   close (fdp);
   close (fdc);
   exit (0);
}
```

This is the second one

```
//FILE DECRYPTION

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void merror(char *msg) {
  perror(msg);
  exit(0);
}

char *Decriptar(char *Key, char *Msg, int size) {
  static char* Res;
  int n=0;
  DES_cblock      Key2;
  DES_key_schedule schedule;
  Res = ( char * ) malloc( size );
  memcpy( Key2, Key,8);
  DES_set_odd_parity( &Key2 );
  DES_set_key_checked( &Key2, &schedule );
  DES_ecb_encrypt((unsigned char *)Msg, (unsigned char *)Res,&schedule,DES_DECRYPT);
  return (Res);
}

#define LINELEN 8
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int n, fdp, fdc;
char key[]="password";
unsigned char buf[LINELEN];

if (argc<3) {fprintf(stderr,"USO %s <fileC> <fileP>\n", argv[0]); exit(0);}

if ((fdc = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
merror ("Open FDP");
if ((fdp = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 00744)) == -1)
merror ("Open FDC");

while ((n = read(fdc, buf, LINELEN)) > 0) 
write (fdp, Decriptar(key, buf, n), n);

close (fdp);
close (fdc);

exit (0);
}
```

But, the plain text I got from the decipher es not the same as the plain text I used to create mi cipher text.

Comment: In `Encriptar` you allocate a smaller buffer than is necessary to hold the DES output.  This means you're throwing away part of the ciphertext (not to mention overrunning your buffer).  Think of any cipher in ECB mode (once keyed) as a method for representing a giant lookup-table---i.e., for decrypt, think of the ciphertext as the index that you use to lookup the plaintext. If you change the ciphertext *at all* you look up a different plaintext, and there's no predictable relationship between the values looked up for "similar" indices.

Comment: Also see [block cipher what is pkcs padding](https://www.google.com/search?q=block+cipher+what+is+pkcs+padding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DES ECB is a block mode cipher with a 64-bit (or 8-octet) block and is **designed to work only on** data that is **a multiple of the block size**. Plus OpenSSL `DES_ecb_encrypt` isn't really ECB *mode* but rather the DES block *primitive*: it encrypts or decrypts one block of exactly 64 bits not less and not more. What you are trying to do should not and cannot work.

Properly-designed cryptosystems that need to handle variable-length data, which many do, either use a stream cipher, a stream mode (like CTR), or a block mode (but not ECB, see below) with padding -- there are a number of standards to choose from; OpenSSL's `EVP_{Encrypt,Decrypt,Cipher}*` module uses PKCS5/7 padding by default, although you can turn it off.

---

Note DES has been broken and obsolete for two decades, and in most applications where ECB mode has been used even with a good primitive it allows attacks that reduce or eliminate security. If you intend to actually secure something, drop this and use a program designed by someone who knows what they are doing -- but that's offtopic for SO.

---

More ontopic for SO, your program uses the wrong pointer type for the calls to `DES_ecb_encrypt`, which your compiler should have detected and warned you about; however, because of the way C defines arrays it is unlikely any implementation will actually fail because of this error. Also you didn't #include the required prototypes for `exit malloc memcpy` and this could result in bugs or crashes on a system with `size_t` larger than `int`.

Comment: ...this is SO, not SX ;-)

Comment: thank you very much, this is a homework that I had from my security class, so I have tried everything, and that's why I was asking here. Now I think I'm gonna try something to add more bits to my plain text before ciphering it. I think it should work

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b: thanks; my brain must have overheated or something